# Hibernate & nested set components & cascade options

Tags: hibernate, one-to-one

When I put some elements into the set and store the entity containing them they does not get persisted into the database... why is that? Cascade="all" does not work for some reason. I use the normal approach, as usual: calling persist method in transaction. Other properties of the entity gets inserted into the database judging by SQL debug statements.

Here's the code:

```
<component name="scheduleManager">

        <set name="b" table="TableB" cascade="all">
            <key column="b_id" />
            <composite-element
                class="example.clazzA">
                <nested-composite-element name="x"
                    class="classX">
                    <property name="x_a" column="x_a" />
                    <property name="x_b" column="x_b" />
                </nested-composite-element>
            </composite-element>
        </set>

    </component>
```